How to change from manual scaling to rule based scalling in azure?

Is there a way to update from manual scaling to rule based scaling using runbooks ?
I tried getting the json and running it but it didn't work, I gave permissions to my automation-account so it can access the storage account but it still doesn't get my json, the error that I'm getting is about the format of the json


Do you want to change scaling method to Rule based in app service using Automation account? Is this your question?

yes, i want to do that

Hi @Antonio Pop, You can use PowerShell script to change the scaling settings and use the same script in Automation account, here is the Stac link to setup automation account.

You can use a PowerShell script to change the App Service Plan scale settings and use the same script in an Automation Account to automate the process. Follow the Stack link that I answered regarding automation configuration.
$Rule1 = New-AzAutoscaleRule -MetricName "Requests" -MetricResourceId "/subscriptions/b93fb07a-6f93-30be-bf3e-4f0deca15f4f/resourceGroups/Default-Web-EastUS/providers/microsoft.web/sites/mywebsite" -Operator GreaterThan -MetricStatistic Average -Threshold 10 -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -ScaleActionCooldown 00:05:00 -ScaleActionDirection Increase -ScaleActionScaleType ChangeCount -ScaleActionValue "1"
$Rule2 = New-AzAutoscaleRule -MetricName "Requests" -MetricResourceId "/subscriptions/b93fb07a-6f93-30be-bf3e-4f0deca15f4f/resourceGroups/Default-Web-EastUS/providers/microsoft.web/sites/mywebsite" -Operator GreaterThan -MetricStatistic Average -Threshold 10 -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -ScaleActionCooldown 00:10:00 -ScaleActionDirection Increase -ScaleActionScaleType ChangeCount -ScaleActionValue "2"
$Profile1 = New-AzAutoscaleProfile -DefaultCapacity "1" -MaximumCapacity "10" -MinimumCapacity "1" -StartTimeWindow 2015-03-05T14:00:00 -EndTimeWindow 2015-03-05T14:30:00 -TimeWindowTimeZone GMT -Rule $Rule1, $Rule2 -Name "adios"
$Profile2 = New-AzAutoscaleProfile -DefaultCapacity "1" -MaximumCapacity "10" -MinimumCapacity "1" -Rule $Rule1, $Rule2 -Name "SecondProfileName" -RecurrenceFrequency Minute -ScheduleDay "1", "2", "3" -ScheduleHour 5, 10, 15 -ScheduleMinute 15, 30, 45 -ScheduleTimeZone GMT
Add-AzAutoscaleSetting -Location "East US" -Name "MySetting" -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-EastUS" -TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/b93fb07a-6f93-30be-bf3e-4f0deca15f4f/resourceGroups/Default-Web-EastUS/providers/microsoft.web/serverFarms/DefaultServerFarm" -AutoscaleProfile $Profile1, $Profile2

Reference: Is There a way to scaleout App Service plan using powershell by Konstantinos Passadis

I get this error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MetricNamespace'."
